# Script - Terminate SSH Connection if user exits script

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I have a shell script that runs in CentOS and the code is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
dialog --menu "Please choose the server to connect to:" 10 30 15 1 RAS01 2>temp

#OK is pressed
if [ "$?" = "0" ]
then
        _return=$(cat temp)

        # Option 1 selected
        if [ "$_return" = "1" ]
        then
                dialog --infobox "Connecting to server ..." 5 30  ; sleep 2
                telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
        fi

# Cancel is pressed
else
        exit 5
fi

# remove the temp file
rm -f temp
```

The idea behind this script is that it will load automatically when the user logs in and is intended to be an idiot-proof way to connect to different servers in the system. Therefore we want to terminate the ssh connection if the user:

- Selects the Cancel Option from the Dialog menu
- If the user exits the telnet connection it originated and returns back to the server the script is ran.

I tried using the exit 5 and exit 1 options but that only exits the script but does not close the connection.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set the script as login shell instead of the normal shell, and any way the script terminates should disconnect immediately. I'd recommend not testing with your only user that can log onto the system.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson how do I do that? I added this script to the .bashrc file and it loads automatically once the user logs in. Is that what you are referring to? Pardon my doubts, I am barely starting with Linux

Comment: You can use the `chsh` command to change a user's login shell. Not on a linux machine right now though, so can't give you the exact command.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I'll research that command around. If you can later point me in the right direction I will also appreciate it as well.

Comment: which do you mean, `ssh`, as in your title, or `telnet` as in your code? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I actually mean both. Since this script automatically loads when the user logs in then in the dialog menu if the user selects Cancel it should terminate the script and the ssh connection it did to the server. However, if the user selects OK and establishes a telnet connection to an external server... once the user is done at that other server it bounces back to the active ssh connection. We want to also terminate the ssh connection once the user returns back from the telnet connection. Does this make it a bit clearer? Let me know